# Warning tensorflow:Early stopping conditioned on metric `val_loss` which is not available

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

i'm getting tensorflow warning and the warning comes after the last iteration where the val_accuracy and val_loss calculated

code of my cnn is-

```
metric = 'val_accuracy'
callback_list = [
    EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',patience=10),

    ModelCheckpoint(filepath="model.h5",monitor=metric,save_best_only=True,verbose=1)]

model.fit(training_set,
            steps_per_epoch = 37,
            epochs = 25,
            validation_data = val_set,
            validation_steps = 7,
            callbacks=callback_list
         )
```

and the output screen is :-

```
Found 9081 images belonging to 6 classes.
Found 0 images belonging to 6 classes.
Epoch 1/25
37/37 [==============================] - 134s 3s/step - loss: 1.7911 - accuracy: 0.1926
WARNING:tensorflow:Early stopping conditioned on metric `val_loss` which is not available. Available metrics are: loss,accuracy
WARNING:tensorflow:Can save best model only with val_accuracy available, skipping.
```

Comment: `Found 0 images belonging to 6 classes.`: Your validation dataset is empty.

Comment: @Lescurel Thank you. I didn't notice that part. later i executed it successfully

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The validation dataset provided while training is empty or doesn't contain any data. So, the warning pops up. Make sure your are not using any hardcoded value for data split.